# Splitting an image into 4 pieces using python JES

Tags: python, jes

How do I split an image in JES? I am a new IT student and i just need a guide how to go about it, I have tried `def splitImage(filename):`
and I loaded the program but its coming up with an invalid syntax. I am not sure what am doing wrong

Comment: Can you post your code and the full error message please.

Comment: ====== Loading Progam =======
Invalid syntax
Your code contains at least one syntax error, meaning it is not legal jython.
The error is on line 2
>>>  my code def splitImage (filename)

Comment: i can pick the file but not sure how to split it, this is what i did to pick my image file = pickAFile()
pic = makePicture(file) 
show(pic)